# Erro na minha estrutura de dados [PILHA]

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, stack

Meu código está apresentando dois erros. Como estou aprendendo, eu já tentei de várias maneiras de consertar. Por favor, alguém pode me ajudar ?

Eu preciso inserir um número e uma string na minha pilha. Mas está dando erro na minha estrutura.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define MAX 5

typedef struct Ligacacao {
        char hora[MAX];
        int numero;
        struct Ligacacao *prox;        
        };

char hora[MAX];
int numero;
Ligacacao *topo; //ERRRRRRO


void dados_ligacao() {
     printf ("\nEntre com a hora da chamada: ");
     fflush (stdin);
     fgets (hora, MAX, stdin);
     printf ("Entre com o numero do telefone: ");
     fflush (stdin);
     scanf ("%d", &numero);
}
void push_ligacao() {

     dados_ligacao();
     Ligacacao *pnovo=(Ligacacao*)malloc(sizeof(Ligacacao)); //ERRRRRRO
     strcpy(pnovo->hora,hora);
     pnovo->numero=numero;
     pnovo->prox=NULL;
     if(topo==NULL)//se a pilha estiver vazia
     topo=pnovo; //topo recebe o novo elemento
     else{
          pnovo->prox=topo; 
          topo=pnovo;
          }
}

void pop_ligacao() {
     Ligacacao *aux;
     if(topo==NULL){
                    printf ("\n\nErro, Sem ligacoes.\n\n");
                    return;
                    }
                    else{
                         aux=topo;
                         topo=topo->prox;
                         free(aux);
                         }
}

void listar_ligacao() {
     Ligacacao *aux;
     aux=topo;
     while(aux!=NULL){
                      printf ("\t\t\tDados Ligacao\n\n");
                      printf ("Numero: %d", aux->numero);
                      aux=aux->prox;
                      } 
}

int main() {
    char op;
    topo=NULL;
   do{
       system("cls");
       printf ("\t\t\Ligacoes");
       printf ("\n\n(E)mpilhar Ligacacao\n");
       printf ("(L)istar Estoque Ligacacaos\n");
       printf ("(D)esempilhar Ligacacao\n");
       printf ("(S)air do Programa\n\n");
       printf ("Digite a opcao: ");
       op=toupper(getche());
       switch(op){
                  case'E': push_ligacao();
                  break;
                  case'L': listar_ligacao();
                  break;
                  case'D': pop_ligacao();
                  break;
                  case'S': exit(0);
                  default: printf ("\n\nOpcao invalida, digite novamente.\n\n");
                  }       
                  system("PAUSE");
                  }while (op!='S');
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está dando erro onde? Eu rodei aqui, usei E para empilhar, digitei uma hora e um número de telefone (ambos inteiros), depois coloquei para listar e estavam lá.

Aqui apareceram duas mensagens: 
`unknown escape sequence '\L'` na linha 70:

```
printf ("\t\t\Ligacoes");
```

Esse último \ é desconhecido porque o \L não é uma sequência de escape (como \n e \t), então é só retirar e deixar

```
printf ("\t\tLigacoes");
```

Outra mensagem apontada foi `'typedef' foi ignorada nesta declaração`, na linha 12:

```
typedef struct Ligacacao {
        char hora[MAX];
        int numero;
        struct Ligacacao *prox;        
        };
```

Isso aconteceu porque não é necessário usar a palavra `typedef` neste caso, basta retirar e deixar:

```
struct Ligacacao {
        char hora[MAX];
        int numero;
        struct Ligacacao *prox;        
        };
```

Com essas alterações, compilou sem apresentar nenhum warning.

Comment: agora reparei que na sua struct hora é um vetor de char, rodei novamente e inseri uma string, deu tudo certo da mesma forma... se o erro for outro tenta colocar uma imagem pra ver se posso ajudar